# How to add a "chromecast connection success" callback method in our iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, chromecast

I would like to add a chromecast callback delegate method to my project(for succesfull chromecast connection), so that when the connection is established, I will continue to play the video in Chromecast device.

> I'm using the latest chromecast SDK. ver 3.3.0.

```
- (void)deviceManagerDidConnect:(GCKDeviceManager *)deviceManager;
```

This protocol method and the delegate property is defined in the class,

```
"GCKDeviceManager"
@property(nonatomic, weak, readwrite, GCK_NULLABLE) id<GCKDeviceManagerDelegate> delegate;
```

From this SDK update, we don't create or maintain the GCKDeviceManager objects in our project, SDK takes care of it.
So I couldn't set my video player as the delegate to "GCKDeviceManagerDelegate".

How to set our class as a delegate for "GCKDeviceManager" ?
i.e, How to get the object reference of "GCKDeviceManager" class ?

Is there any other way to get a callback from chromecast receiver on successful connection ?

Comment: what the problem u faced

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I've updated the question.

Comment: How to get the object reference of "GCKDeviceManager" class, so that we can set our class as the delegate to "GCKDeviceManagerDelegate" ?

Comment: ya got it create another one protocol and set the delegate ,it will be call

Comment: Creating another protocol will not solve the issue, as the GCKDeviceManager class will call the delegate method like this.
"self.delegate.deviceManagerDidConnect(self)"
So our new protocol won't help in transferring this message to my custom classes in the project.

Comment: but in my current project I create the common class for fetch the device connection after that i used the delegate for play the video

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to achieve this from the sample projects provided by Google.
Do not use `GCKDeviceManager class's delegate property`
Use `"GCKSessionManagerListener"` to add our class as the listener like,

```
GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager.addListener(self)
```

Now, when the cast connection is established, I get a call back to this method,

```
func sessionManager(sessionManager: GCKSessionManager, didStartSession session: GCKSession)
```